How to Preserve ORDER BY Logic with Multiple CTEs in Trino?
I have a Query, in Trino engine, that I am creating several CTEs but I am losing the ORDER BY logic when I add the CTEs
Its like this:
WITH AS CTE1(...)

CTE2 AS (.....ORDER BY 2)

CTE3 AS(...)

CTE4 AS(...)

FINAL SELECT * FROM CTE4

I want to know how to make the final result have the same ordering as the first ORDER BY
I tried adding the same ORDER BY in all CTEs and I also tried adding the ORDER BY in the final query. These two ways result in different orderings for cases with the same ID. And I need it to be perfectly aligned with the CTE2 that has the order by. This 'disorder' happens after the insertion of new CTEs

Add a sequence column to the (desired) cte result. ORDER BY that column in your final select.

ORDER BYs in anything other than a final SELECT statement have no effect on the result. You appear to be ordering by the 2nd column in CTE2 so just order by that column wherever it is in CTE4 (and drop the order by in CTE2 as all it does is potentially slow down your query)


I want to know how to make the final result have the same ordering as the first ORDER BY

I need to add ordering to the final query. Trino is a distributed SQL query engine designed to query large data sets and for performance reasons it can handle data in highly parallel fashion which makes preserving "original" ordering either a relatively costly operation (so it is not done by default) or maybe even impossible in some cases (also I have some doubts that there are a lot of engines that support maintaining ordering in such case, though not an expert here).
So just apply required ordering in the final query:
SELECT * 
FROM CTE4
ORDER BY ...

If you don't want to have the ordering column in the final result you will need to still propagate it to the final query and skip it in the select:
SELECT fiedl1, field2 
FROM CTE4
ORDER BY ignoredOrderingField


This was one of the first things I tried. I tried adding the same ORDER BY in all CTEs and I also tried adding the ORDER BY in the final query. These two ways result in different orderings for cases with the same ID. And I need it to be perfectly aligned with the CTE2 that has the order by. This 'disorder' happens after the insertion of new CTEs

@ThiagoMelo if your data has several rows for the same ordering combination then Trino will never guarantee you the resulting ordering (for IMHO obvious reasons). You need to add some "tie-breaker"/unique column to the ORDER BY clause.

It makes sense... The query itself is actually quite large (+300 lines). There is a spreadsheet and I need to create a query to automate it, so it is extremely important that the order of my query is the same as that of the spreadsheet

@ThiagoMelo it is hard to tell without seeing the data. Also you can use some window functions  (like row_number) to generate some synthetic unique ordering for the query (though it can change between queries).

Thanks friend. I think I need more specifications to "break the tie" in the ordering of cases with the same ID. Because when I don't specify, what you said happens: the bank decides who turns first. So I have to better specify my order by so that the choice is mine and not his. That said, I think it's impossible for me to exactly replicate the ordering of the spreadsheet, since it's random.

@ThiagoMelo "I think I need more specifications to "break the tie"" - TBH not sure how much more clear I can be here. You need to add another column to the ordering so it will "break the tie".  "That said, I think it's impossible for me to exactly replicate the ordering of the spreadsheet, since it's random. " - you can preprocess the file adding one more column - row_number based on the "physical" order of lines. Though it should be done outside of Trino/Presto.
